# vb generate random number for Form location

Tags: vb.net, random, integer, location

i'm making a visual basic program in Visual Studio, where a rather large amount of Forms will show. However, they all popup together in a bunch and only some of them are visible. I'm wondering if there is a way to generate a random integer between two numbers, then setting it as the location of the `New Form1`.
Right now I have this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick 
        Dim more As New Form1
        (Code for generating random number from 1 to 999)
        (Code for generating new random number from 1 to 999)
        more.Location = New Point(random number, new random number)
        more.Show()
        time = 10
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `Random` class.  Lots of examples online.  If you'd simply searched the web for "vb.net generate random number" then you'd have found them.  You shouldn't be posting a question here without searching the web first.  We're here to help but with hard stuff, not stuff you can find in 30 seconds with a search.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow. The thing is, I usually search it up and get answers from this site, but I didn't find any answers precisely to my question, so I decided to ask it directly. Thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way its a little bit easier

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim more As New Form1
    Dim rn As New Random
    more.Location = New Point(rn.Next(0, 999), rn.Next(0, 999))
    more.Show()
    time = 10
End Sub
```

And this is the code that can use all your screen space

```
Dim rn As New Random
Dim mxw As Integer = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width - Me.Width
Dim mxh As Integer = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height - (Me.Height + 29 + 38)
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim more As New Form1
    more.Show()
    more.Location = New Point(rn.Next(0, mxw), rn.Next(0, mxh))
    time = 10
End Sub
```

Ok i don't realy understand what you mean by `new` random number so if this doesn't solve your problem explain it better.

Comment: I meant that I wanted to generate a random number, set it as x, then create a new (different) random number, and set it as y. I'm going to test your answer though, because I think it might work.

Comment: On every timer tick?

Comment: The full thing was that when the timer ticks, the countdown goes down, and when the number  in `TextBox1.Text` is 0, it will execute the code for the random location of the `New Form1`, and set the countdown back up to 10.

Comment: Nothing, actually. I was just explaining because you said you didn't really understand why I said `New` random number. I just need to test it out.

Comment: Anyway. If it works mark it as the answer. Btw with the max number to 999 you can't use all your screen space. If you want to use all of it I can give you the code :)

Comment: Yes please! I was gonna mark your answer, don't worry! Anyways, apparently we're not supposed to have extended conversations in comments, and I don't have enough reputations to chat, since I just joined. So I have to stop talking, sorry. (I got a message warning me about this) P.S. I just used 999 as an example.

Comment: Ok i edited the code (The bottom one uses all your screen space)

Comment: Sorry dude, the code didn't really work, but I think it's my fault (I'm a beginner). But i'm sort of able to use it on another project right now so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you should be able to use this.  Basically, it allows you to set your upper and lower limits and then set it to x and y coordinates.  I specifically do not declare the x and y variable.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick 
        Dim more As New Form1
        Dim upperLimit As Integer
        Dim lowerLimit As Integer
        lowerLimit = 1
        upperLimit = 999
        x = Int ((upperLimit - lowerLimit + 1) * Rnd + lowerLimit)
        y = Int ((upperLimit - lowerLimit + 1) * Rnd + lowerLimit)
        more.Location = New Point(x, y)
        more.Show()
        time = 10
End Sub
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `Rnd` in VB.NET.  We're not in VB6 anymore Toto.

Comment: When I read the question, I swear I thought it said MS Access on not vb.net, but apparently I am a goof!  Agreed on Random class.